# Cannot find module express-validator with dockerized node app

Tags: node.js, docker, express, express-validator

I've installed `express-validator` with `npm install --save express-validator` in my node app but I'm receving the following error:

```
module.js:478
express-mongo |     throw err;
express-mongo |     ^
express-mongo | 
express-mongo | Error: Cannot find module 'express-validator'
express-mongo |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
express-mongo |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
express-mongo |     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
express-mongo |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
express-mongo |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/validation/validator.js:1:98)
express-mongo |     at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
express-mongo |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
express-mongo |     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
express-mongo |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
express-mongo |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
express-mongo |     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
express-mongo |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
express-mongo |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/user-geolocation.route.js:3:43)
express-mongo |     at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
express-mongo |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
express-mongo |     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

This are the dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mongo-crud": "^1.3.0",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.7"
  }
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:boron
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

In the app I'm just requiring it like this:

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
```

This is my `docker-composer.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/services/app/Dockerfile
    container_name: express-mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
```

Any idea about what could be the issue here?

Comment: There's a common Node/Docker pattern that actively prevents Docker from seeing any updates in your `package.json` file.  How are you running the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm running ```docker-compose up --build```. I'm now trying with removing some not so important dependencies from the ```package.json``` file but it does re-run ```npm install``` and ```express-validator``` is being installed.

Comment: Please add your `docker-compose.yml` file to the question.  If you have a `volumes:` declaration for your `node_modules` directory, that directly causes this.

Comment: Why would be the ```node_modules``` volume declaration causing it? Sorry if it's a silly question, I'm new to docker.

Comment: It's a declaration that the directory contains critical user data that must be preserved across container runs and not modified.  Contrary to popular belief, it is not a way to bypass bind-mounting the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for in Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD npm start
```

Comment: Please explain a little more